# LightDM starts, but nothing happens

Tags: alpine-linux, lightdm, openrc

I'm using Alpine Linux, OpenRC

Unlike many other questions similar to this one, LightDM does seem to start, but after that... Nothing happens. Command line seems normal, and just like all the other TTYS. So what may be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by reinstalling Alpine.